# Скрытие отображения кнопки в хедоре

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ionic, angularjs-controller

У меня есть такой index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<ion-side-menus>
<!-- Left menu -->
<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-list class="l-menu-list">
        <ion-item class="header-list item-avatar" href="#/main/tips">
            <div class="img">
                <img ng-src="img/menu-avatar.png">
            </div>
            <div class="name">Fabrice Dan</div>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Astuces</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Maladies</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Numéros utiles</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Souscrire à « Plus d’Astuces »</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Souscrire à « Pharmacies de garde »</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Inviter des amis</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Paramètres du compte</p>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item href="#/main/tips">
            <p>Déconnexion</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-side-menu>

<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable main" ng-controller="navBarCtrl">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left" class="button button-clear button-positive">
            <i class="icon ion-android-menu" ng-click="toggleLeftMenu()"></i>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button button-clear">
            <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
        </ion-nav-back-button>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="button button-clear button-positive">
            <i class="icon ion-android-search"></i>
            <i class="icon ion-android-more-vertical" ng-click="showDetails()"></i>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

При переходе на внутренние страницы, к примеру по такой ссылке

```
http://localhost:8888/nouseful
```

Кнопка (ниже) должна отображаться, а при переходе на внутренние страницы типа:

```
http://localhost:8888/nouseful/1
```

и дальше, вместо этой кнопки должна появляться кнопка возврата на предыдущую страницу.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left" class="button button-clear button-positive">
      <i class="icon ion-android-menu" ng-click="toggleLeftMenu()"></i>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Answer (score 2):

$scope.isBackButtonActive - в контроллере проверка на url

```
<button ng-if="!isBackButtonActive">Вперед<button>
<back-button ng-if="isBackButtonActive">Назад<back-button>
```